# In Rust, how to push an object with a lifetime into a vector?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, lifetime-scoping

I've got code somewhat like the following, which attempts to read from a websocket, parse the JSON result into a struct, and push that struct onto a `Vec` buffer. The code however fails to compile, because the struct has a lifetime, and the borrow checker complains that the JSON string does not live long enough.

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use tungstenite::client::AutoStream;
use tungstenite::protocol::WebSocket;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
struct MyType<'a> {
    id: &'a str,
    count: i64,
}

fn example<'a>(
    conn: &mut WebSocket<AutoStream>,
    buff: &'a mut Vec<MyType<'a>>,
) -> Option<Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    match conn.read_message() {
        Err(err) => Some(err.into()),
        Ok(msg) => {
            let resp_raw = msg.to_string();
            let resp_parsed: Result<MyType<'a>, _> = serde_json::from_str(&resp_raw);
            match resp_parsed {
                Err(err) => Some(err.into()),
                Ok(resp) => {
                    buff.push(resp.clone());
                    None
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exact error is that `borrowed value [&resp_raw] does not live long enough`.

I'm wondering how I should restructure this code to satisfy the borrow checker; what is the correct way to push a struct with a lifetime onto the `Vec` param?

Or is it the case that the `&'a str` parsed into `MyType` actually still retains a reference to the original JSON string, so there's no way to safely do this?

Comment: Why are you using a `&str` for `id`? If it's a reference, then the ID needs to be owned by something else, but your code specifically creates a struct from a strong and then discards the string, so nothing would own the ID. Can `id` be a `String` instead?

Comment: Could you paste a working playground link (without dependencies to tungstenite)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `serde_json::from_str` carefully:

```
pub fn from_str<'a, T>(s: &'a str) -> Result<T> 
where
    T: Deserialize<'a>,
```

This says that the `T` which is deserialized shares the same lifetime as the input `s`. This *allows* for zero-copy deserialization, which is what you get in `MyType`, where `id` is a reference to a string slice. This binds the lifetime of `MyType` to the lifetime of `&resp_raw`, which is local to `fn example()`. This will not work.

The problem can't be solved by giving `buff` the lifetime-parameter you've given it. The `example`-function owns the buffer that `MyType` point into. Allowing `MyType` to "escape" into the `Vec` would allow a dangling reference to be created, as the buffer is destroyed once `example` returns.

Change `MyType` to satisify `DeserializeOwned`, that is, take no lifetime parameter. You'll need a `String` or a (to safe a little memory) a `Box<str>` instead of a `&str`.